# How to solve "Communications link failure" problem on a Spring Boot Application using mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, heroku

I've developed a Spring Boot Application based on Heroku's ["Getting Started on Heroku with Java"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java). After that I've started configuring mysql as the database. [This](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) is the tutorial I've followed throughout this approach. Everything works great when I run the application locally with `heroku local web`. I can make GET requests and get data stored in database. I can make POST requests and add new data to database. But if I deploy it to production, I see exceptions thrown in the logs. Below is the related part of the log that I see when I start the application running on url Heroku provided me, in this case: https://danef-dictionary-api.herokuapp.com/

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1 
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1202) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1233) [hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) [spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) [spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) [spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) [spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
Jan 04 02:24:27 danef-dictionary-api app/web.1  at net.danef.DanefDictionaryApiApplication.main(DanefDictionaryApiApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
```

From the exceptions, I've picked up the first one, "Common link failure" and used it in the title of this question. I've probably tried everthing I can find as a solution so feel free to redirect me if you know a blog post or answer you think that is helpful.

My application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_words?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=myusername
spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

"myusername" and "mypassword" are just placeholders. I'm using my credentials on my code.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.danef</groupId>
    <artifactId>danef-dictionary-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>danef-dictionary-api</name>
    <description>Danef Dictionary API</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Refer to this link if you want to see the full version of logs: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wqZPXqyYFM/

Comment: @mangusta Without a problem, yes.

Comment: @mangusta The there's nothing to do in the code side. Is that true? I've tried connecting from another network and it was the same. So I don't give much chance to that. Is there a way that I can be sure it's firewall or something else that is blocking the connection?

Comment: do you use `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_words` as your DB url to connect from production? if yes, not surprising that it can't connect (unless DB is located on the same host as production server).

Comment: Yes. This is the URL I'm using on production too. I've tried setting up a different one. It had exact numbers instead of localhost. But I couldn't make it work. What is the URL that I need to use?

Comment: if your DB server has a public IP address (those 4 numbers separated by dots), replace `localhost` in the original URL with that number: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/db_words?useSSL=false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem by setting up ClearDB addon in Heroku. After adding the addon, I've had a remote database URL. Setting the remote URL as datasource.url solved the problem. My application.properties file looks like this now.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://`remote_database_url`
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=samet
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Set your remote database URL without backticks.

Comment: Instead of hard coding the JDBC URL, you should use `$JDBC_DATABASE_URL` or `$SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`

Comment: Okay. Where do I need to declare them?

Answer (score 1):

When we are working in container(spring app) to container(mysql) communication mode.

- In application.yml or properties add the mysql container name in url, example:
  `jdbc:mysql://<container_name>:3306/movie_rest_service`
- Port is important: Mysql will be waiting in 3306, even if you mention other port in mysql run, example:
  `docker run --name mysqldb -d -p 3307:3307 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Mysql123 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=movie_rest_service -e MYSQL_USER=user1 -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=Mysql123 project/mysql`
  [image]
- Build the App jar by disabling test.
- Run Mysql image
- Run App image, example:
  `docker run -t --link <mysql_container_name>:mysql -p 8080:8080 <app image name>`

Answer (score 0):

Our java application is deployed in Kubernetes pod (container)

I was facing this issue and it got resolved when we changed the driver from `jdbc:mysql` to `jdbc:mariadb` in application.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to change mysql config file

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

I changed the line:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind-address = ::
```

If the bind address is ::, the server accepts TCP/IP connections on all server host IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces. Use this address to permit both IPv4 and IPv6 connections on all server interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker-compose to create your database and another docker-compose to your application you need to use the **name of the service** you gave...
Suppose the **docker-db.yml** is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  vehicles-dbserver:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSOWRD=root123
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=user123
    volumes:
      - /opt/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - application
networks:
  application:
```

The **docker-app.yml** should be:

```
version: "3"
services:
  vehicles-api:
    image: application/vehicles
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - DATABASE_USER=user
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=user123
      - DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://vehicles-dbserver:3306/vehicles-database?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      - DATABASE_DRIVER=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    networks:
      - application
networks:
  application:
```

The point of attention is "DATABASE_URL=jdbc:mysql://**vehicles-dbserver**:3306"

Answer (score 0):

If you sure about all the version of ide, driver, mysql etc and still is nothing working then go to ide check java version and it's vendor. I prefer oracle and opejdk java vendor.

I was getting same error and I wasn't able understand why this error while all settings are correct and I checked java version and it's vendor. after changing it it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes while installing the MySql workbench we select the option of "MySql service not starting automatically".
This can lead to a situation when after system restart your MySQL server won't start and STS may give this error.

If this is the case you can go to
`Windows->Services->mySql service->Properties->start service manually`.

This way your MySql workbench will start working properly and STS can successfully connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently Spring tries to communicate with the database and cannot which is strange, since the database should have been created with the `docker-compose up ...` command.
I managed to solve my problem as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<db_local>:3306/<your_db>?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

This forces Spring to create the database if it does not exist.

But unfortunately I didn't understand the problem in my case, as docker-compose is supposed to upload the database. As happy as I am to finally fix this, I'm still unhappy that I don't understand where the problem was.
I'm going to leave my database service here for anyone who wants to see and point out any defects.

```
db:
  image: mysql:8.3.0
  container_name: app_db
  platform: linux/x86_64
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
   volumes:
    - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  restart: 'always'
  healthcheck:
    test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin" , "ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
    timeout: 10s
    retries: 5
  cap_add:
    - SYS_NICE # Should omit minor alerts
  networks:
    - network
```